# How to lock back screen on yotaphone?

Tags: java, android, sdk

Can I set up pin or password to backscreen programmatically? I couldn't find such methods in yotaphone sdk.
I think, I need something similar to main screen lock:

```
    DevicePolicyManager manager = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    manager.lockNow();
```